# Issues upgrading OpenSSL to 1.0.2 on Mac(Yosemite)

Tags: python, macos, openssl

I'm running python 2.7.11 and am trying to upgrade openSSL from version 0.9.8 to 1.0.2

I ran the command `brew install openssl` and things seemed to install correctly. However, openSSL has not been updated

```
$ openssl version
    OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015

$ brew install openssl
    Warning: openssl-1.0.2h_1 already installed

$ brew link --force openssl
    Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1
    To relink: brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl
```

It looks like things have been installed but I'm not familiar with what steps to take to get things squared away.

**EDIT** I updated my path as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew) so that */usr/local/bin* came before */usr/bin* and I get the following:

```
$ openssl version
    OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

However, in python it's running the old version

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
   OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

Comment: Also see [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661) and [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858). Its not clear to me which duplicate you are experiencing, but the questions have been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED NO HACKS, none of the above worked for me. I ended up taking a simpler and uncomplicated approach....

1. Install python 2.7.13 from the official site, it actually installs as the default python, upgrading the old python system wide.

https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

2. Upgrade openssl after the python install, effect is system wide.

*sudo pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL*

3. You will have to re-install all your python modules ( because you replaced python ), I strongly recommend using pip. After a few minutes of pip installs my default OSX python was upgraded, I had openssl upgraded, and I had all my modules ( including django running ).