# Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 in Python (on Travis CI OSX image)?

Tags: python, macos, openssl, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I have **OpenSSL 1.0.2 installed**.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

**Exported compiler flags** as advised.

```
before_install:
- export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
- export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
- export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Still, **Python sees OpenSSL 0.9.8** only.

```
$ python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION;'
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

So later on, when I try to run [this](https://github.com/eppz/Unity.Test.eppz/blob/master/.scripts/install-unity.py) Python script, it says:

`ERROR: Your Python's OpenSSL library is outdated (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016).`

**How can I fix the OpenSSL reference in Python?**

---

I tried a whole lot of things: https://github.com/eppz/Unity.Test.eppz/commits/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Is your python installation very old? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230057/7675174) might help if you want to try homebrew.

Comment: It is 2.7.14. Thanks for the link. Unfortunately somewhy Travis CI don't let me use `--with-brewed-openssl`. It says `Warning: python: this formula has no --with-brewed-openssl option so it will be ignored!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `python2`** instead `python` to run scripts.

You can try this simple `ssl` version check:

```
$ python2 -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION;'
OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
```