# pip fails due to SSL cert TLSv1.0

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Apologies for another pip issue, but I've tried almost every other thread and nothing so far works.
So I am having the issue that pip doesn't install any package due to using TLSv1.0
`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping`

I have done the curl to download the get_pip.py script then executed it with sudo python.

I have tried downloading the pip.tar.gz manually, extracting it and installing via `pip install ./pip.10.0.3`

Once installed, I have done `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

I have installed python via Homebrew.

`pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

However every time I still get this TLSv1 error when attempting to install a package, and it shows I have TLS1.0 in use

`python2 -c "import urllib2,json; print(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())['tls_version'])"
TLS 1.0`

Running OSX 10.13.4

EDIT: 
`python2 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

`$ brew upgrade openssl
Error: openssl 1.0.2o_2 already installed`

EDIT2:
Followed the thread here, the topmost answer and eventually worked
[Python referencing old SSL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323858/python-referencing-old-ssl-version)

`$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`

Comment: Can you try the same steps in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version), and add them to your question? It might make it easier to help if we know what you've tried.

Comment: edited.........

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew upgrade openssl
Error: openssl 1.0.2o_2 already installed
```

This shows that a newer version of openssl is indeed installed on your system.

```
python2 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

But this shows that Python's ssl module was compiled against an older version.

I am unfamiliar with Homebrew, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/8974) on Homebrew's Github page, Homebrew now uses its own version of `openssl` by default.

Based on this, the full steps to fix this issue would be:

```
brew uninstall python2
brew update
brew upgrade openssl
brew install python2
```

Comment: just uninstalled python via Homebrew, and reinstalled with the flag you suggested, `brew install python2 --with-brewed-openssl
Warning: python@2: this formula has no --with-brewed-openssl option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/8974) on Homebrew's Github page, `--with-brewed-openssl` is no longer needed, because the install uses Homebrew's version of openssl by default. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: just uninstalled all python's, then brew install python@2.... still uses 0.9.8 OpenSSL

Comment: I noticed your `pip --version` command says it was loading pip from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip`. Is this the version installed by Homebrew? Homebrew's docs says it install under `/usr/local/bin/`?

You can confirm this by trying `which python` in a new Terminal.