# Why do HTTPS requests produce SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error?

Tags: python, ssl, request, certificate

Here is my Python code:

```py
    import requests
    requests.get('https://google.com')
```

This is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

Using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) gives me an error related with certificates:

[image: Error shown in Insomnia]

My OS is Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: requests.get('https://google.com')

Comment: I don't think it's related with the code

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify='/path/to/certfile')
```

or you can skip verifications by doing this:

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)
```

You should specify your CA.

Comment: Yesterday I was able to request without passing this parameter, By the way how can I get a google domain certificate ?

Comment: I'm consuming from a API that I don't have the control. And why other softawers can't make a HTTPS requests ?

Comment: I've tried it without specifying CA and it worked as well, which is weird.

Comment: Yes, I tryed this same code in another machine. And guess what? It's worked.

Comment: Just use `verify=False` to ignore the ssl.

Comment: But I'm using some lib that uses request internaly.. And I can't change the code. And what about the http clients like Insomnia? I think there are some problems with the SO

Comment: In the browser I can request HTTPS

Comment: I think should change requests.get('https://google.com', verify='/path/to/certfile') to  requests.get('https://google.com', verify= True, cert=['path/to/cert/files])

Answer (score 5):

If you are running under business network, contact the network administrator to apply required configurations at the network level.

Comment: I think this may be my issue. What configurations would these be?

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it: [Python referencing old SSL version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858/13476428)

The openssl versions used to differ for python and the one offered by homebrew

if 
`brew install python --with-brewd-openssl`
doesn't work
try
`brew install openssl
brew install python`
after uninstalling python

Answer (score 3):

You might add header and verify argument to by-pass ssl certificate security.

```
r = requests.get(URL, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'}, verify=False)
```

You should specify path your certificate if you have.

Comment: This will, of course, remove the benefits SSL certificates give you, including verification that you are actually talking to the server you think you do, and are not being affected by a man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 3):

If you using proxy server,add proxy to your requests.
just like:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://localhost:port','https':'http://localhost:port'}
requests.get('your_request_website', headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: where do you find localhost:port if are not specified ?

Answer (score 2):

In the `requests.get` you can set the `verify` flag to `False`. This way the handshake between the program and the server is going to be ignored.

-- This isn't a guaranteed method because some servers have strict policy to deliver responses to requests.

Answer (score 0):

in Chromadb Web loader this worked for me

```
loader = WebBaseLoader([root_url])
loader.requests_kwargs = {'verify':False}
```

See you

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my problem by installing openssl
you can go here and download the Light version or any version suited to your needs:
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html