# Python call to request() to SSL site not pointing to netrc

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Testing out a simple piece of code with Anaconda3:

```
import requests as req

resp = req.get("https://api.github.com")
print(resp.text)
```

And I get this error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Using the debugger to follow the calls, the problem seems to be occurring in `get_netrc_auth()` in requests.utils.  Here, this code is used to get the full path to the netrc file:

```
        for f in NETRC_FILES:
            try:
                loc = os.path.expanduser('~/{}'.format(f))
```

However, this just gives the path to my home directory, whereas netrc is in the `Lib` directory of the working environment.

Apparently, I have an environment variable set incorrectly somewhere.  Suggestions?

**EDIT TO QUESTION:**
Per Steffen's response, netrc does not appear to be the problem.  Marsiliou's suggestion on directly including the path to the cert file (i.e. 
    `resp = req.get("https://api.github.com" verify='/path/to/certfile')`) did work... once... yesterday.

My code now looks like this:

```
import requests as req
from os import environ

cert_path = environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + '\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem'
print (cert_path)

resp = req.get("https://api.github.com", verify= cert_path)
print(resp.text)
```

`cert_path` expands to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`
This results in the same SSLError.  Any suggestions (other than setting `verify` to `False`)?

PS - And to answer Steffen's other questions - This is Anaconda3, Python 3.7.3, on Windows 10.

Comment: I very much doubt that the problem is triggered from inside `get_netrc_auth`. The problem is an improper setup of the trust store which means that the certificate can not be validated. Unfortunately nothing is known about your system (OS?, exact version of Anaconda3?) so it is hard to tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan.  Yes, you're correct; that particular issue was something of a red herring.  To answer your other questions:  Windows 10, Python 3.7.3.  Marsilinou's answer did solve my problem, but it also raised a question:  since ```certifi``` is referenced by ```requests,``` and ```cacert.pem``` is part of ```certifi,``` why does it have to be referenced explicitly in the function call?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is answered here, did you try this?
[SSL HTTS requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51768580/8692977)

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that answers it, sort of.  However, since cacert.pem is included in the certifi package (which is referenced the the requests package), should it not be pulled in automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add a User-agent

```
import requests as req
# these import are for the verify false to avoid having a warning in the console
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

Headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
}
resp = req.get(url="https://api.github.com",headers=Headers, verify=False)
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: The code works perfectly without any specific user agent once the trust store is properly setup. The code complains about failed certificate validation. Certificate validation done during the TLS handshake which is before even the HTTP  request is send is thus before any User-Agent setting will take effect.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know that that's why I added the verify false but I encountered a similar issue where the user-agent was the solution to it So I said don't forget to add it Just in case there was nothing wrong with the certificate