# SSLError while requesting my API with Flask

Tags: python, api, flask, request

I developped an API (endpoint : https://helloworld.mycompanyname that I need to request with a parameter 'key' ). I want to access this API from my front so I'm trying this method :

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=("POST","GET"))
def test():
   payload = {'key':'****'}
   r = requests.get('https://helloworld.mycompanyname/', params=payload)  
   return r.text
```

And I have this SSLerror :

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='helloworld.mycompanyname', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?key=*** (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

How can I fix that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768496/ssl-htts-requests-exceptions-sslerror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-google-com-po

Check if this helps

Comment: Already checked. I don't want to add 'verify=False' because Adding certificate verification is strongly advised

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python are you using ? If you are using the older version then you end up getting SSL Error try to upgrade to 3.4 or latest. It should resolve your issue.