# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to connect Informatica cloud from python script and sending POST call to the server. But it is failing with an unknown protocol error.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import requests

url = "https://xxxxxx.com/informatica/identity-service/api/v1/Login"

payload="{\r\n    \"username\": \"xxxxx\",\r\n    \"password\": \"xxxxxx\"\r\n}"

headers1 = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'keyId': 'xxxxxxx'
}

response = requests.request('POST', url, data=payload, headers=headers1, verify=False )
```

The same POST request is working fine in postman toll and getting response correctly. But hitting with ssl unknown protocol error while invoking post through Python script.

I am executing both Python & Postman in Windows10.

Can anyone assist me to resolve this error?

Error Message:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /informatica/identity-service/api/v1/Login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),))
```

Python version - 3.6.2
pip version - 21.0.1
openssl version - OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Comment: 443 means you made too many requests so you need to wait until the next one. Check in the docs for request limit

Comment: I am not sending multiple requests. Its a single request to create a login session. The same POST request to create login session is working in Postman tool which is also I am running it on the same machine where I am running the python script.

Comment: Try adding a user agent and making payload a dic instead of a string.

Comment: no luck. I am still getting same error. payload={'username': 'xxx',
        'password': 'xxx'} 
I tried with all below different User agents in the request. Its not working for all of them.
'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/8.0.7'
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'
User-Agent':'python-requests/2.24.0'

Comment: @DeadSec 443 is the port and has nothing to do with the HTTP status code.

Comment: @BradSolomon just noticed that. Sorry about that. Wasn't paying attention, probably.

Comment: @DeadSec Do you think of any other issue on this.

Comment: Try HTTP instead of https

Comment: No, the link is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade your OpenSSL version?

Comment: we downgraded the Request version to 2.24.0. it resolved the SSL issue.

Comment: on a side note, you are sending username and password in payload. hope that's encrypted

Comment: this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768496/why-do-https-requests-produce-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error