# urllib.request.Request - How to send csv files as input in the request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I need to send csv file as input in the request along with url,data & headers as this is import request. But the Request is not supporting the files. Can you assist me how to send files input in the urllib.request.

headers = {
'SESSION-ID': 'xxx',
'keyid': 'xxx'
}

```
payload = {"delimiter":"COMMA","textQualifier":"DOUBLE_QUOTE","codepage":"UTF8",
              "dateFormat":"ISO"}
payload1 = json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8")

payload2 =  {'importSettings':payload1}
data = json.dumps(payload2).encode("utf-8") 
#print(data)  
    
files = [('file',('import.csv', csvstr,'text/csv'))]

url = xxx


try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers,files=files)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
        res = f.read()
        print(res.decode())
        return res  

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Getting this error - **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'

Comment: For some reason, I am getting SSL error when I am using requests. So I replaced the request with urllib.request. (SSL error link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66653440/httpsconnectionpoolhost-port-443-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-caused-b?noredirect=1#comment117853301_66653440) .

Comment: yes.I did. But It did not resolve the SSL error. Is there a way to send files as one of the input with Urllib.request.

Comment: ok thanks. Let me check it.