# SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)'))

Tags: python, python-requests

'''HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.xxxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rupload_video/1654677618121_0_6985510698 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)')))'''

Getting this issue when I use multi-threading and uploading multiple videos to a server

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask good questions. And I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51768580/15837436) is the answer to your question ?

Comment: I am randomly getting this error as well when downloading many files. The cert is correct, and we do not want to do verify=false (guessing same problem here if it is working w/out multi-threading).