# Python not working (ImportError) when I try to use pip on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install gym for my assignment and did `pip install gym` and got this output. Anaconda and jupyter notebook also do not work when it used to work perfectly before. I tried uninstalling python and reinstalling but that did not solve the issue. Would anyone know how to fix this?

Note: I use Mac OS

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2714, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2332, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2338, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 8, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

EDIT: This forum solved it for me: [Python referencing old SSL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323858/python-referencing-old-ssl-version) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python2.7 package is dependent to the `libssl1_0_0` package (openssl_1.0 runtime librairies).

Install it, and add the `/usr/local/ssl/lib` directory in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environnent variable.

To set it,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib"
```

Can you also update me on the output of running this cmd if the earlier solution doesn't work `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"`

Comment: Yeah the first option didn't work for me, and I got this output: `OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018`.

Answer (score 0):

Literally dealing with the same issue today, its an issue with openssl but im still working to resolve it

*edit - actually this just worked for me, `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s` youre switching to an older version of openssl.  pip and everything works for me now

Comment: I tried this but it says: `Error: openssl does not have a version "1.0.2s" in the Cellar.
openssl's installed versions: 1.0.2p` :(