# Use urllib or requests to get data from URL

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to use urllib, urllib2 or requests in order to get specific data from a site. I use Python2.7.
I keep getting an error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

This is my code with requests:

```
  import requests
  r = requests.get("https://metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov/jtwc#_48_INSTANCE_0SiamlX2KcM6_=https%3A%2F%2Fmetoc.ndbc.noaa.gov%2FProductFeeds-portlet%2Fimg%2Fjtwc%2Fhtml%2Fcoop.jsp%3F")
```

I have tried everything but nothing works:

I tried to set the verification parameter to false. I get the same error.
  I tried to use an adaptor (as described in other answers) in order to use another SSL version. I still get the same error.

Any ideas what can the issue be? 
Can it be that the host has locked the access and there is no possibility to get the source for this URL?

Comment: Works for me. I get a bunch of javascript mainly.

Comment: The code works fine for me.

Comment: What sub-version of Python 2.7 are you using, and on what version of what OS?

Comment: Guys this is really strange. I use python 2.7.10. We have tried these in 3 different computers. All of them in macs with Yosemite or ElCapitan. Can this be related?

Comment: Version of Elcapitan is 10.11.5. Here you can see similar error: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2627

Comment: Are all the computers on the same network?

Comment: Nope. I tried also from my personal Mac at home.

Comment: running `openssl s_client -connect metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov:443 -ssl3` `SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:339`

Comment: also mounting a custom adapter http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version and issuing the request gives me the same error in python, try explicitly setting the version to tls. http://pastebin.com/WUsRwqMj FWIW `ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23` also works

Comment: @user1919 You get the same sslv3 error explicitly setting tls? The server will not accept any sslv3 even with ECDHE encryption

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham yup. I get the same error although I set tls. I can post my code tomorrow when I go at work.

Comment: But more or less I followed this here: https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/

Comment: Maybe a silly question but you did use s to make the request ? i.e the session object?

Comment: Yes. Sure. After mounting it, I use s.get("https...")

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham tomorrow I will try to do what described here: http://techiezone.rottigni.net/2016/03/python-2-7-11-on-el-capitan-with-tls-1-2-support/

Comment: One last thing what does `openssl version` output from bash?

Comment: it gives this: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

Comment: OK then we have the problem, you are still using the old openssl version, from memory I downloaded the binary and just replaced the /usr/bin/openssl
 with the new. I imagine brew may install in somewhere like usr/local or the mac equivalent

Comment: So it would be ok if I remove the existing openssl from /usr/bin and copy there the one I installed with brew? Or download the binary one from ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/  Right?

Comment: I downloaded the binary from the ftp site and just did a sudo mv etc.., there shouldn't be any logocla reason that it would cause any issue, that is exactly what I did when i wne tfrom 0.9.8 to 1.0.1f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All of them in macs with Yosemite or ElCapitan...

These versions still come with OpenSSL 0.9.8 so my guess is that your python is linked against this version of OpenSSL (python does not use the native TLS stack in OS X). But since the server only supports ECDHE ciphers and these are not supported by OpenSSL 0.9.8 the handshake will fail. See the [report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! So what would be my options here?

Comment: @user1919 upgrade your openssl ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I have updated my openssl using brew. This didn't solve the issue!

Comment: Did you try  setting the adapter using tls as per the link I added to the comments?

Comment: @user1919: it is not enough to update openssl but it has to be linked with python. To check what version of openssl your python is using check `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7 for more information for how to update your python to include a newer version of openssl.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich thank you. The procedure described in the link made things work!