# How to update OpenSSL on mac?

Tags: python, c, macos, ssl, openssl

I need to ensure that I have OpenSSL version of 1.0.1 or greater to connect to the Salesforce API according to [this documentation](https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox).

According to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x), I can do the following steps (which I've completed successfully)

1. brew update
2. brew install openssl
3. brew link --force openssl

When I run `openssl version -a`, I get the following:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: /usr/bin/clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/local/etc/openssl"
```

However, when I run `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"`, I get the following:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

I'm getting mixed signals from my computer, but my salesforce module is still not working, so I know OpenSSL is not updated completely on my computer.

I should also mention that I've also tried:

```
sudo port upgrade openssl
```

Port seemed to have worked, but when I run `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` I still get that I'm on "OpenSSL 0.9.8zh"

Is there another way to update OpenSSL?

Comment: I am not sure, but this might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27230127/2694511

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a multi-part issue with the versions of Python you are using and your `$PATH` variable.

First check where you're looking for Python by using this command in the terminal:

```
which python
```

It should output something like this: `/usr/local/bin/python`

Then check for the path that you have setup.

```
echo $PATH
```

Likely you're seeing something like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The issue is probably that the version of python tied to your default when you enter `python` in your terminal is not one that has the modern version of openssl.

In other words:

```
openssl version -a
```

Is checking for openssl somewhere different than

```
python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
```

To fix this, you might try editing your `$PATH` variable.

I suggest doing this by editing something like your `~/.bash_profile` file. You can add something like this to specify a different Python binary to use:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Plop this on the end of your `.bash_profile` file and then whenever you're using bash it should look for Python in the `/usr/local/bin` directory before looking elsewhere. Keep in mind that this might also affect places that other programs look for Python (or other binaries).

Answer (score 1):

@fernando's answer had the right theory but his recommendation for a next step didn't work for me, because `/usr/local/bin` was already first in my $PATH. Here's how I fixed mine:

In the response for `brew info python` I saw:

`==> Caveats
This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.
If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add the following to ~/.bash_profile:
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

I added that last line to my `~/.bash_profile`, opened a new terminal window, and it worked.