# OpenSSL version error

Tags: php, mongodb, openssl

When I am trying to install a mongodb extension for XAMPP with php7 through PECL, it shows me error:

```
checking whether to enable developer build flags... no
checking whether to enable code coverage... no
checking whether to use system libbson... no
checking whether to use system libmongoc... no
checking configuring libmongoc... ...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: OpenSSL version 1.0.1 or greater required.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config' failed
```

But if I prompt "openssl version", it shows:

```
MacBook-Pro-dns:~ soldatov$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

I tried a lot of stuff found with internet to fix it... But it continue to throw me error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update OpenSSL on mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467916/how-to-update-openssl-on-mac)

Comment: presence of command-line openssl binary does not imply presence of openssl headers (which are required for compilation)