# How to update OpenSSL for Python 2.7 without using homebrew

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ssl, openssl

When executing different scripts with **Python 2.7.14**, I keep running into Errors that seem to lead back to my **OpenSSL** installation.

E.g. when using `requests`:

```sh
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:661)
```

I'm on:

- Python 2.7.14
- MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.3
- **NOT** using <kbd>homebrew</kbd> ! (and would prefer not to)

Mac OS uses [LibreSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreSSL):

```sh
$ openssl version -a
LibreSSL 2.6.5
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"

$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

However, my Python installations (from source) both use **OpenSSL** - two different versions:

```sh
$ python2.7 -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

$ python3.7 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018
```

I want to **update the OpenSSL** used with Python 2.7 without using `homebrew` (nor Anaconda), and without using an additional package, such as `pyOpenSSL`.

Most solutions I can find online suggest using `homebrew` and therefore don't answer my question:

- [Updating openssl in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x
- https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401

None of my Python versions are installed using `homebrew` and I'd like to stay clean from further complicating my OS setup.

Considering that different versions of OpenSSL are installed, should I follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467916/how-to-update-openssl-on-mac) and link Python 2.7 to the newer OpenSSL version?

- Is that the best way to move forward?
- What can go wrong?
- What are viable alternatives?
- Any good resource for learning to navigate the SSL-Python-jungle on Mac?

Comment: After checking with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), I think it might related to the issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46188850/5717580) - even though [the page supports TLS 1.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=free-proxy-list.net&s=104.27.149.235), which should thus work with my OpenSSL 0.9.8zh version that Python 2.7 is using?

Comment: *"None of my Python versions are installed using homebrew and I'd like to stay clean from further complicating my OS setup."* - it is unclear how your existing versions where installed. If updated versions can not be installed the same way then you need to recompile everything by hand, which definitely complicates your OS setup more than just using homebrew or Anaconda.

Comment: They are downloaded from the official Python download page: https://www.python.org/downloads/ and installed using the installer that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the currently installed versions were the ones provided by python.org itself it should be sufficient to simply download and install the latest version again. Given the old version of OpenSSL on the 2.7.14 binary it looks like that this was compiled against the old version shipped with MacOS. With 2.7.15 this was changed as can be seen on the [download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/):

> Attention macOS users: as of 2.7.15, all python.org macOS installers **ship with a builtin copy of OpenSSL**.

Thus, you can expect to have a recent OpenSSL in Python 2.7 just by installing the official version of 2.7.15 provided by python.org. Note that this is also  the case for the Python 3.7 you already have.