# requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, ssl, handshake, sslv3

I have a script that's made in python as below

```
#!/bin/env python2.7

# Run around 1059 as early as 1055.
# Polling times vary pick something nice.
# Ghost checkout timer can be changed by 
# adjusting for loop range near bottom.
# Fill out personal data in checkout payload dict.

import sys, json, time, requests, urllib2
from datetime import datetime

qty='1'

def UTCtoEST():
    current=datetime.now()
    return str(current) + ' EST'
print
poll=raw_input("Polling interval? ")
poll=int(poll)
keyword=raw_input("Product name? ").title()       # hardwire here by declaring keyword as a string 
color=raw_input("Color? ").title()                # hardwire here by declaring keyword as a string
sz=raw_input("Size? ").title()                    # hardwire here by declaring keyword as a string
print 
print UTCtoEST(),':: Parsing page...'
def main():
    global ID
    global variant
    global cw
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', "User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25")
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = json.loads(resp.read())
    ID=0
    for i in range(len(data[u'products_and_categories'].values())):
        for j in range(len(data[u'products_and_categories'].values()[i])):
            item=data[u'products_and_categories'].values()[i][j]
            name=str(item[u'name'].encode('ascii','ignore'))
            # SEARCH WORDS HERE
            # if string1 in name or string2 in name:
            if keyword in name:
                # match/(es) detected!
                # can return multiple matches but you're 
                # probably buying for resell so it doesn't matter
                myproduct=name                
                ID=str(item[u'id'])
                print UTCtoEST(),'::',name, ID, 'found ( MATCHING ITEM DETECTED )'
    if (ID == 0):
        # variant flag unchanged - nothing found - rerun
        time.sleep(poll)
        print UTCtoEST(),':: Reloading and reparsing page...'
        main()
    else:
        print UTCtoEST(),':: Selecting',str(myproduct),'(',str(ID),')'
        jsonurl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/'+str(ID)+'.json'
        req = urllib2.Request(jsonurl)
        req.add_header('User-Agent', "User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25")
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        data = json.loads(resp.read())
        found=0
        for numCW in data['styles']:
            # COLORWAY TERMS HERE
            # if string1 in numCW['name'] or string2 in numCW['name']:
            if color in numCW['name'].title():
                for sizes in numCW['sizes']:
                    # SIZE TERMS HERE
                    if str(sizes['name'].title()) == sz: # Medium
                        found=1;
                        variant=str(sizes['id'])
                        cw=numCW['name']
                        print UTCtoEST(),':: Selecting size:', sizes['name'],'(',numCW['name'],')','(',str(sizes['id']),')'

        if found ==0:
            # DEFAULT CASE NEEDED HERE - EITHER COLORWAY NOT FOUND OR SIZE NOT IN RUN OF PRODUCT
            # PICKING FIRST COLORWAY AND LAST SIZE OPTION
            print UTCtoEST(),':: Selecting default colorway:',data['styles'][0]['name']
            sizeName=str(data['styles'][0]['sizes'][len(data['styles'][0]['sizes'])-1]['name'])
            variant=str(data['styles'][0]['sizes'][len(data['styles'][0]['sizes'])-1]['id'])
            cw=data['styles'][0]['name']
            print UTCtoEST(),':: Selecting default size:',sizeName,'(',variant,')'
main()


session=requests.Session()
addUrl='http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/'+str(ID)+'/add.json'
addHeaders={
    'Host':              'www.supremenewyork.com',                                                                                                                     
    'Accept':            'application/json',                                                                                                                             
    'Proxy-Connection':  'keep-alive',                                                                                                                                   
    'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',                                                                                                                               
    'Accept-Encoding':   'gzip, deflate',                                                                                                                                
    'Accept-Language':   'en-us',                                                                                                                                        
    'Content-Type':      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                                            
    'Origin':            'http://www.supremenewyork.com',                                                                                                                
    'Connection':        'keep-alive',                                                                                                                                   
    'User-Agent':        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257',                               
    'Referer':           'http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile'   
}
addPayload={
    'size': str(variant),
    'qty':  '1'
}
print UTCtoEST() +' :: Adding product to cart...'
addResp=session.post(addUrl,data=addPayload,headers=addHeaders)

print UTCtoEST() +' :: Checking status code of response...'

if addResp.status_code!=200:
    print UTCtoEST() +' ::',addResp.status_code,'Error \nExiting...'
    print
    sys.exit()
else:
    if addResp.json()==[]:
        print UTCtoEST() +' :: Response Empty! - Problem Adding to Cart\nExiting...'
        print
        sys.exit()
    print UTCtoEST() +' :: '+str(cw)+' - '+addResp.json()[0]['name']+' - '+ addResp.json()[0]['size_name']+' added to cart!'

    checkoutUrl='https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout.json'
    checkoutHeaders={
        'host':              'www.supremenewyork.com',
        'If-None-Match':    '"*"',
        'Accept':            'application/json',                                                                                                                             
        'Proxy-Connection':  'keep-alive',                                                                                                                                   
        'Accept-Encoding':   'gzip, deflate',                                                                                                                                
        'Accept-Language':   'en-us',                                                                                                                                        
        'Content-Type':      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                                            
        'Origin':            'http://www.supremenewyork.com',                                                                                                                
        'Connection':        'keep-alive',                                                                                                                                   
        'User-Agent':        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257',                               
        'Referer':           'http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile'   
    }

    #################################
    # FILL OUT THESE FIELDS AS NEEDED
    #################################
    checkoutPayload={
        'store_credit_id':    '',      
        'from_mobile':              '1',
        'cookie-sub':               '%7B%22'+str(variant)+'%22%3A1%7D',       # cookie-sub: eg. {"VARIANT":1} urlencoded
        'same_as_billing_address':  '1',                                    
        'order[billing_name]':      'anon mous',                              # FirstName LastName
        'order[email]':             'anon@mailinator.com',                    # email@domain.com
        'order[tel]':               '999-999-9999',                           # phone-number-here
        'order[billing_address]':   '123 Seurat lane',                        # your address
        'order[billing_address_2]': '',
        'order[billing_zip]':       '90210',                                  # zip code
        'order[billing_city]':      'Beverly Hills',                          # city
        'order[billing_state]':     'CA',                                     # state
        'order[billing_country]':   'USA',                                    # country
        'store_address':            '1',                                
        'credit_card[type]':        'visa',                                   # master or visa
        'credit_card[cnb]':         '9999 9999 9999 9999',                    # credit card number
        'credit_card[month]':       '01',                                     # expiration month
        'credit_card[year]':        '2026',                                   # expiration year
        'credit_card[vval]':        '123',                                    # cvc/cvv
        'order[terms]':             '0',
        'order[terms]':             '1'                
    }

    # GHOST CHECKOUT PREVENTION WITH ROLLING PRINT
    for i in range(5):
            sys.stdout.write("\r" +UTCtoEST()+ ' :: Sleeping for '+str(5-i)+' seconds to avoid ghost checkout...')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
    print 
    print UTCtoEST()+ ' :: Firing checkout request!'
    checkoutResp=session.post(checkoutUrl,data=checkoutPayload,headers=checkoutHeaders)
    try:
        print UTCtoEST()+ ' :: Checkout',checkoutResp.json()['status'].title()+'!'
    except:
        print UTCtoEST()+':: Error reading status key of response!'
        print checkoutResp.json()
    print 
    print checkoutResp.json()
    if checkoutResp.json()['status']=='failed':
        print
        print '!!!ERROR!!! ::',checkoutResp.json()['errors']
    print
```

When I want to run it everything goes correctly but at the end it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/"USERNAME"/Desktop/supreme.py", line 167, in <module>
    checkoutResp=session.post(checkoutUrl,data=checkoutPayload,headers=checkoutHeaders)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 522, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: Please don't use external links to show your code since the external links could be broken in the future and that will make your question invalid. You should include your code *inside the question* itself. I've included the code for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.supremenewyork.com) the server supports only TLS 1.2 and supports only very few ciphers. Given a path like `/Users/...` in your error output I assume that you are using Mac OS X. The version of OpenSSL shipped with Mac OS X and probably used by your Python is 0.9.8, which is too old to support TLS 1.2. This means that the server will not accept the SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0 request from your client.

For information on how to fix this problem by updating your OpenSSL version see [Updating openssl in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7).