# Python SSLError, sslv3 alert handshake failure, for wallhaven.cc

Tags: python, ssl, pyopenssl

Python Version: 3.5.2

OS: OS X 10.12

OpenSSL Version: OpenSSL 1.1.0b  26 Sep 2016

I'm trying to requests "https://alpha.wallhaven.cc".

```
import urllib.request
init_page=urllib.request.urlopen("https://alpha.wallhaven.cc")
```

Then get

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)
```

and

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)>
```

The following solutions don't work:

```
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS='ALL'

import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

import requests
print(requests.get("https://alpha.wallhaven.cc",verify=False))
```

or change /APNSWrapper/connection.py line 131:

```
ssl_version = self.ssl_module.PROTOCOL_SSLv3,
```

into

```
ssl_version = self.ssl_module.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
```

Then what is the problem? How to solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> OpenSSL Version: OpenSSL 1.1.0b 26 Sep 2016
>   ...  sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)>

I do not doubt that you have OpenSSL 1.1.0b installed on your system but I doubt that this version is actually used by your python. Usually MacOS has the old version 0.9.8 of OpenSSL installed and unless one [compiles python to use another openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7) this version will be used, even if other OpenSSL versions are installed somewhere on the system. To check what version of OpenSSL is used by your python:

```
  import ssl
  print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
```

If this shows `OpenSSL 1.1.0b...` I'm wrong in my assumption but if this shows 0.9.8 I'm right with the following argumentation:

- `handshake failure` indicates a problem which is not related to certificate validation.
- Looking at the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=alpha.wallhaven.cc&s=104.28.20.70&latest) I can see that the server only suppors ECDHE ciphers.
- ECDHE ciphers are not support by OpenSSL version 0.9.8
- therefore there are no shared ciphers between client and server and the handshake fails

Answer (score 0):

> The following solutions don't work ... 
>   `print(requests.get("https://alpha.wallhaven.cc",verify=False))`

You should probably avoid that `verify=False` thing.

Here's what works from the OpenSSL point of view. Be sure you are doing three things in your Python code:

- Using Server Name Indication (`-servername` below)
- Using TLS 1.0 or above (`-tls1` below)
- Using *"AddTrust External CA Root"* (`-CAfile` below)

You can find the *"AddTrust External CA Root"* at Comodo's [[Root] AddTrust External CA Root](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/945/0/root-addtrust-external-ca-root). Its already in PEM format.

Below is from OpenSSL's `s_client`. It completes as expected: *`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`*.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect alpha.wallhaven.cc:443 -servername alpha.wallhaven.cc -tls1 -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot.crt 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO ECC Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = sni142395.cloudflaressl.com
verify return:1
Server did acknowledge servername extension.
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=sni142395.cloudflaressl.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=sni142395.cloudflaressl.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4263 bytes and written 263 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: B3D3918537F17225CC5CEFAC956D1CA633EBD1AC0F5FF431B27BADCEA8D768BB
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 3484745B4C605ED65273BC86C58514EF8DD32B7847D7FA188093BBE9192451218E5FA4F3DF11D6CEEA648AFA6FE65CE6
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 64800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c9 ea 35 99 eb cc 0d 9b-57 14 76 91 e1 54 eb 98   ..5.....W.v..T..
    0010 - d4 39 86 bc f3 84 ea 86-16 8d 08 d2 e6 ef 0c 02   .9..............
    0020 - 07 ec cf f7 41 43 9f 7d-5a 3f 92 37 50 28 0a 53   ....AC.}Z?.7P(.S
    0030 - 70 0b 91 cf 66 1e db f5-aa 34 1a f3 59 8e bd da   p...f....4..Y...
    0040 - f5 38 e6 7d 23 9c b5 78-36 92 a9 8e 92 97 09 ec   .8.}#..x6.......
    0050 - bd 7e 39 37 58 59 d2 88-fb 1e 2e c9 02 d7 11 3b   .~97XY.........;
    0060 - 80 01 4b c3 f7 a7 4b 33-4b 2b 0d b0 3f f8 bc 3e   ..K...K3K+..?..>
    0070 - 9f 61 ff dd da 42 ee 06-dd 17 69 5c 08 c0 75 7b   .a...B....i\..u{
    0080 - ac bf 08 22 0b fe 64 b8-19 a0 04 08 07 67 3a bc   ..."..d......g:.
    0090 - 27 24 16 83 87 c3 a2 46-72 e1 fa 96 78 92 36 71   '$.....Fr...x.6q
    00a0 - 58 ab 00 eb d8 b1 b8 e2-6e e2 4e 30 f3 1a 2d 6a   X.......n.N0..-j
    00b0 - 38 7e 29 75 83 d7 45 26-e3 70 0a bf ed 51 a4 1c   8~)u..E&.p...Q..

    Start Time: 1477471636
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

---

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0b  26 Sep 2016
```