# Python and 'print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION' prints wrong version

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyopenssl

I was working with Steffen Ullrich on a previous issue, and now it is morphing into a new issue.  So taking his advice (thank you Steffen), I am posting a separate question:

```
$ python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

I have attempted just about everything under the sun (so it feels) to fix it.

```
$ brew install openssl
Warning: openssl 1.0.21 is already installed
```

So I have both, but it only reads/links to OpenSSL 0.9.8zh?

I am new to Python/Homebrew on my Mac.

Comment: [How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361569), [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858), [Python and OpenSSL version reference issue on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37690054), [Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899573), [Using Python with homebrew on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441252), etc...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install Python that is linked to that Homebrew OpenSSL library, try with:

```
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

Beware, tho, that it will not replace your 'native' Python, you'll have to relink it. By default, it will be installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/<version>`, whereas the `version` may change with time. If you want you can relink the python binary as:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.old 2>/dev/null
sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/python/<version>/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

But I'd suggest you to create a local link so you can use both python versions:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python.old 2>/dev/null
sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/python/<version>/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

(of course, replacing the `<version>` with whichever version of Python Homebrew installed at the time of trying the above)

And then when you need this 'upgraded' Python just launch your scripts with `/usr/local/bin/python script.py` or use `/usr/local/bin/python` as their shebang.

Comment: `$ brew install python --with-brewed-openssl`
    
    `Warning: python 2.7.13 is already installed`
    
    **Next was:**
    
    
    `$ sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python.old 2>/dev/null`
    
`$ sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python` 
    `/usr/local/bin/python`

    **Result:**
    `$ python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'
    OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Yes, you're calling the old, _built-in_ python binary - try: `/usr/local/bin/python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'`

Comment: $ /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017

I think you might have just solved both of the issues I posted questions about...Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else has the same issues, I wanted to provide the link to the original (1st half of the issue) so that others may get a full picture.

[macOS Sierra/Python2.7.13 URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089490/macos-sierra-python2-7-13-urlerror-urlopen-error-eof-occurred-in-violation-of)