# When using requests in python I'm given the following error "TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION." Why might this be happening?

Tags: python, ssl, https

This is my code so far. When using requests in Python I'm given the following error:

```
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION.
```

Why might this be happening?

```
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

     # context = ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO

     # print(context)
     # if event['session']['application']['applicationId'] != app_id:
     #     raise ValueError("Invalid Application ID")

     token = requests.post(html, data={'apikey': api_key}, auth=(username, password), verify=False)

     print(token.text)
     payload = {'token': token}

     requests.post(html_step_two, data=payload,  verify=False)

     payload = {'token': token, 'workflow_id': workflow_id}
     requests.post(workflow_run, data=payload,  verify=False)

     return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of openSSL you use, but it is likely the culprit! It's a fairly common issue, and one that seems to be best resolved by clean installs of both openSSL and Python.

To check which version of openSSL you are using, go to your Python terminal and type

```
import platform
import ssl

print("Python info: %s" % (platform.python_version()))
print("OpenSSL info: %s" % (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))
```

If the OpenSSL info is returned as being `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`, you may experience issues. On my mac, this returns `OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016`, which works with other requests applications I've used in the past.

The solution at this point would probably be to uninstall openSSL and reinstall it! However, you would also probably want to upgrade your installation of brew, as it is likely not [benefitting from an update released last September](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/612) concerning OpenSSL.

After looking at a few examples on the web, I believe the most straight-forward and comprehensive way to reinstall `openssl` and upgrade `brew` (assuming there are not any other issues) is by running:

```
brew uninstall openssl
```

and

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup && brew doctor
```

taking the time to fix any issues brought up by `brew doctor`, before finally running

```
brew install openssl
```

This will ensure you are running the latest version of OpenSSL, and should help resolve the issue!

A side note here, *upgrading Homebrew will update all your installed packages to their latest versions.* This may not be ideal for you if some of your other coding projects are dependent on now-deprecated packages included in previous versions of `brew`. I wouldn't think it to be a large problem, but just an FYI!

If this uninstall of OpenSSL doesn't work for you, there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129977/how-to-install-latest-version-of-openssl-mac-os-x-el-capitan), but I would imagine there to be larger problems if the above solution doesn't work.

Hope it helps!

Sources

- [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129977/how-to-install-latest-version-of-openssl-mac-os-x-el-capitan)
- ["tlsv1 alert protocol version"](https://github.com/kelproject/pykube/issues/80)

Comment: Okay my brew version of openssl is now updated, but the python version hasn't been. I've tried various solutions online but none of them seem to be working. Specifically, I've tried to change my bash profile's path to /usr/local/bin/, and I've tried installing python --with-brewed-openssl, but neither have worked.

Comment: Did you also run `brew upgrade`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I've now tried a couple other things and it still hasn't fixed it.

Comment: I've tried the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew