# Braintree - how to reset retries in braintree

Tags: python, braintree-sandbox

I am using braintree with python and swift.can anyone tell me how to reset retries in braintree.
I am getting this error

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /merchants/merchantid/client_token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)'),))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact?_ga=2.47890466.428332314.1517265210-1868041817.1513354075&_gac=1.204271268.1514392694.EAIaIQobChMIpdjIsNCq2AIVF_5kCh04TA4eEAAYASAAEgJSEfD_BwE).</sub>

The "retries exceeded" error seems to be a red herring that really points to an SSL incompatibility. The `SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` SSLError indicates that the host url [api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com](https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com) will not accept your TLS version. 
Starting on December 16, 2016, Braintree deprecated Sandbox's support of TLSv1.1 in favor of TLSv1.2, you can read about it in [this blog post](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/updating-your-production-environment-to-support-tlsv1-2/).

To fix this issue, you will want to check which version of OpenSSL your machine is running using Terminal:

`$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"`

If the OpenSSL version is not 1.0.1+, you will need to update OpenSSL to the latest version, which supports TLSv1.2. If you are using Homebrew, you can follow the instructions [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7/27230127#27230127).